# Dart JSON Encode/Decode causing error due to extra bracket

Tags: json, flutter, dart

So I have a Flutter app which I'm trying to save some data locally as a JSON file. I'm doing this using `dart:convert` and `jsonEncode` and `jsonDecode` and a Dart Map, but for some reason when I save the Map to a file using `file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(map))`, it seems to be adding a phantom end bracket to the end like so (not consistently either it doesn't seem):

```
{
  "posts_in_progress":       
    {
 "https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/chtbl.com/track/9EE2G/pdst.fm/e/rss.art19.com/episodes/67461d56-cdd8-4b03-a957-3edb110232d4.mp3":73035
    }
}
}
```

This then causes an error when trying to read and decode this file with `jsonDecode(file.readAsString())` because of the extra bracket.

What is causing this extra bracket? And how can I prevent this from happening or handle for the extra bracket when its there on the decoding side?

Edit:
LocalServices file which handles all the local data json storage. It doesn't seem to always happen and be easily reproducible, but it has happened multiple times (before I was just handling the local file saving and reading within other methods, but tried to create this local services class to help fix it, still haven't figured out what causes it tho).

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class LocalService {
  bool _isInitialized = false;
  Map data;
  String filepath;
  String filename = 'local_data.json';
  File file;

  initialize() async {
    filepath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((directory) => directory.path);
    file = await File('$filepath/$filename').exists() ? File('$filepath/$filename') : null;
    if(file != null) {
      print('Local Data File Exists, start decoding... \n${await file.readAsString()}');
      data = jsonDecode(await file.readAsString());
      print('Decoding complete!');
    } else {
      file = new File('$filepath/$filename');
      data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    }
    _isInitialized = true;
  }

  update() async {
    if(!_isInitialized) {
      await this.initialize();
    }
    try {
      data = jsonDecode(await file.readAsString());
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error Updating file: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> setData(String key, dynamic value) async {
    if(!_isInitialized) {
      await this.initialize();
    }
    try {
      data[key] = value;
      await file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(data));
      await update();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error writing update to file: $e\n$key/$value');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example of your issue.

Comment: I've added my LocalServices file, which does all of this JSON and local data handling. The thing with this error has been I haven't figured out what causes it or how to make it happen consistently. It's happened multiple times on a few different devices tho (Android and iOS).

Comment: Please reduce the code to just what isn't working and make it clear what isn't. There are a few functions there and I don't know where the issue is.

Comment: I've removed the `getData()` function, but the other three I think are involved in whatever the issue is. I suspect something in `setData()` is causing the extra bracket to be inserted into the string, and then both `initialize()` and `update()` actually throw the error due to them containing `jsonDecode()` which fails due to the malformed brackets.